# Differentiable limit function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differentiability of $s=\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} {1\over (x-n)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65912/differentiability-of-s-sum-limits-infty-infty-1-over-x-n2)

Why is $f=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ where $f_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-n}^n {1\over (x-k)^2}$ differentiable on $\mathbb R-\mathbb Z$? I know that the $f_n$'s are continuous and converge pointwise to $f$, but then it doesn't converge uniformly to $f$... so...?